# zgrep first match for each line in a file

Tags: grep

I am trying to use zgrep -f to find, for each line of a query file, just the first match in a single to-be-searched file. Because the to-be-searched file is enormous (~3GB), it's crucial that, if zgrep finds one match for a current query line, it stops that search and then searches for the pattern on the next line of the query file. My problem is that "zgrep -m 1 -f" will only find the first match for the first query line of the query file; then it stops reading the query file entirely.  Is there some other way to combine the -m and -f (z)grep options that will perform this search more efficiently?

Here are two lines from my 1000-line query file structure (wordList.txt):

```
^dog 
^cat
```

And three lines from my 3-million-line(?) to-be-searched file (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt.gz)

```
dog 0.017198 -0.007493 -0.057982 0.054051 -0.028336
accordion 0.012590 -0.003692 -0.014291 0.057166 -0.025180
cat 0.004059 0.067190 -0.093874 0.071370 0.038900
```

And unfortunately this command:

```
% zgrep -m 1 -f wordList.txt GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt.gz > myVectors.txt
```

returns only the first match for the first query:

```
dog 0.017198 -0.007493 -0.057982 0.054051 -0.028336
```

Whereas this command (without the "-m 1"):

```
% zgrep -f wordList.txt GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt.gz > myVectors.txt
```

Returns the full expected output, but takes infinitely longer because it searches the entire file every time:

```
dog 0.017198 -0.007493 -0.057982 0.054051 -0.028336
cat 0.004059 0.067190 -0.093874 0.071370 0.038900
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: I ended up writing a tiny bash script as a wrapper for the single-query "zgrep -m 1", so I'm pasting it below in case someone else runs into a similar problem. Adding the short-circuit ability sped up my searches by ~95%:

```
#!/bin/sh
for L in `cat wordList.txt`; do
    zgrep -m 1 "$L " GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt.gz >> myVectors.txt
done
```